# SDL Web 8 Legacy pack

Tags: web8

Can you confirm if SDL Web 8 will support the legacy pack (for VBScript sites that are still in existence from a previous R5 upgrade) or is this completely removed and applications will need to be migrated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, SDL Web 8 will still have the legacy pack. This is the last version that will have support for VBScript/COM templates.

Comment: Really, we mean it this time! :)

Comment: :) really really really mean it now.